# Error while loading shared libraries: libpangolin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, lib, orb, slam

I am fairly new to ROS and trying to implement an ORB_SLAM2 example. I receive a few other similar errors to this with libraries and I could solve them. However, in this case I have no idea what is `libpangolin`.so is.

Can someone help me to solve this issue.

I am running the following command;

> $ rosrun ORB_SLAM2 Mono /Path/To/ORB_SLAM2/Vocabulary/ORBvoc.bin
>   /Path/To/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/Monocular/TUM1.yaml

Answer (score 0):

> Pangolin is a lightweight portable rapid development library for managing OpenGL display / interaction and abstracting video input

Your ROS node expects the shared libary of Pangolin which is not installed at your system. Install the library like described at the [GitHub repository of Pangolin](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin). After installation you should be able to run your node. Make sure, the shared library is installed and recognized by your system.